# i am having trouble understanding return values

Tags: java, return

so for this program i have to use a method that should return -1 if the first             circle is smaller, return 0 if the two circles have the same size, or return 1 if the first circle is larger.  Based on the return value from this method, the main method    should print a line of output like: 
       The green circle is smaller than the red circle.

```
   but i dont know how to program it to where 

    if (r1 > r2)
       return -1;

    so that the main method prints

   r1 is bigger then r2



   BEFORE CHANGES this is what i had when i asked the question




        import java .awt.*; // for the graphics classs
        import java .util.*;// for scanner class
       public class Circles{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object
        DrawingPanel panel=new DrawingPanel(400,300);
        Graphics gObject = panel.getGraphics(); //grahics object
       // get info on circles
       System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the blue circle");
       int x1=input.nextInt();
       int y1=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter your radius for the blue circle");
        int r1=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the red circle");
        int x2=input.nextInt();
        int y2=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your radius for the red circle");
       int r2=input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the pink circle");
       int x3=input.nextInt();
       int y3=input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("please enter your radius for the pink circle");
       int r3=input.nextInt();
       gObject.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       drawCircle(gObject,x1 ,y1 ,r1);
       gObject.setColor(Color.RED);
      drawCircle(gObject,x2,y2,r2);
      gObject.setColor(Color.PINK);
      drawCircle(gObject,x3,y3,r3);
      compare(r1,r2);
      compare(r1,r3);
      compare(r2,r3);

       }//end of main

      public static void drawCircle(Graphics g, int x1 , int y1 , int r1){
      int X1 = (x1-r1);
      int Y1 = (y1 - r1);

      g.fillOval(X1 , Y1 , 2*r1 , 2*r1);
      }//end of drawcircle
       //start of compare
       public static void compare(int r1 , int r2){
       if (r1<r2){
       System.out.println("Second circle is bigger then The First");

        }
         else if (r1 == r2){
           System.out.println("the circles are the same");

         }
          else if (r1 > r2){
            System.out.println("Second is smaller then First");

            }

       }}
```

here is the modified that for some reason increased in errors

```
         import java .awt.*; // for the graphics classs
        import java .util.*;// for scanner class
       public class Circles{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object
        DrawingPanel panel=new DrawingPanel(400,300);
        Graphics gObject = panel.getGraphics(); //grahics object
          // get info on circles
         System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the blue circle");
         int x1=input.nextInt();
         int y1=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your radius for the blue circle");
         int r1=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the red circle");
         int x2=input.nextInt();
         int y2=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your radius for the red circle");
         int r2=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your coordnates for the pink circle");
         int x3=input.nextInt();
         int y3=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("please enter your radius for the pink circle");
         int r3=input.nextInt();
          gObject.setColor(Color.BLUE);
          drawCircle(gObject,x1 ,y1 ,r1);
          gObject.setColor(Color.RED);
         drawCircle(gObject,x2,y2,r2);
         gObject.setColor(Color.PINK);
         drawCircle(gObject,x3,y3,r3);
        compare(r1,r2);
          compare(r1,r3);
         compare(r2,r3);
         int cmpResult = compare(r1, r2);
          if (cmpResult == -1) {
         System.out.println("r1 is smaller then r2");
         } else if (cmpResult == 0) {
         System.out.println("r1 and r2 are the same");
          } else {
          System.out.println("r1 is bigger then r2");
         }
          System.out.println("Second circle is bigger then The First");
          }//end of main

         public static void drawCircle(Graphics g, int x1 , int y1 , int r1 ){
           int X1 = (x1-r1);
         int Y1 = (y1 - r1);

          g.fillOval(X1 , Y1 , 2*r1 , 2*r1);
          }//end of drawcircle
          //start of compare
          public static int compare(int r1 , int r2, cmpResult){
        if (r1<r2){
         return -1;

          }
            else if (r1 == r2){
          return 0;

         }
          else if (r1 > r2){
          return 1;

          }

            }   }
```

heres the errors its giving me

```
      3 errors found:
    File: J:\CS Projects\Circles.java  [line: 49]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
   File: J:\CS Projects\Circles.java  [line: 51]
    Error: Syntax error on token "cmpResult", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
   File: J:\CS Projects\Circles.java  [line: 65]
   Error: Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

hopefully thats clear... if you guys need me to post the code i have so far i will

Comment: It's not that clear, to be honest!  What have you tried, and what problem did you encounter with it?

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothetical `compareTo` method "encodes" the comparison result with the (not so) special code:

- When the first circle is smaller, it needs to return `-1`,
- When the circles are the same, it needs to return `0`
- When the first circle is greater, it needs to return `1`.

This means that the main method should do a decoding of the same:

- when it sees `-1`, it must print "smaller",
- when it sees `0`, it must print "the same", and
- when it sees `1`, it must print "greater".

All of this can be done with a sequence of `if`-`then`-`else` statements:

```
int cmpResult = compareTo(r1, r2);
if (cmpResult == -1) {
    System.out.println("r1 is smaller then r2");
} else if (cmpResult == 0) {
    System.out.println("r1 and r2 are the same");
} else {
    System.out.println("r1 is bigger then r2");
}
```

Comment: `isBigger` sounds like it'll return a `bool`.  I'd rename it to `compare` if I were you because that's more idiomatic of Java programs.

Comment: so i placed that example in the main and passed it to the method that was going to use it and i recevied this error.                 1 error found:
File: J:\CS Projects\Circles.java  [line: 51]
Error: Syntax error on token "cmpResult", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token. did i pass the wrong name i did i do something else wrong

Comment: @user2172510 Please update your question with your modified code so that we could spot the error, or paste into pastebin.com, and post a link.

Comment: i updated it with both orginal and updated to make things a little clearer

Comment: @user2172510 This `public static int compare(int r1 , int r2, cmpResult)` should be this: `public static int compare(int r1 , int r2)`.

Answer (score 2):

If `a=5; b=6`. `a>b` returns `boolean` value so you can write like this:

```
    int compare_radius(int a, int b)
    {  
        return (a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0));
    }
```

`(condition)? val1 : val2` is called as `ternary` operator. If condition is `true` it returns `val1` else `val2`. In your case if `a > b` it returns `1` else it will check for `a < b`, if this true then returns `-1` else it will return `0` for `a == b`

Comment: nice and easy! however, it might help to add some clarification as to what this does, I'm not sure he'll understand the ternary operator

Comment: ^^ is right no idea what that does

Comment: its also good to put brackets around nested ternary operations, there are times where it will screw up if you don't. so just change to `(a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0))` I also like it from a readability perspective.

Comment: i under stand what that does thank you